# How to modify database having foreign key in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables: `SurveyOption` and `SurveyQuestion`, in my DbModel.

```
public class SurveyOptions
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid SurveyOptionId { get; set; }
        public Guid? SurveyQuestionId { get; set; }
        public int? Sequence { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string OptionValue { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Guid? ImageId { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class SurveyQuestions
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid SurveyQuestionsId { get; set; }
        public Guid? SurveyMasterId { get; set; }
        public int? Sequence { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1)]
        public string QuestionType { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public bool? Required { get; set; }
        public string ExplanationLink { get; set; }

    }
```

SurveyQuestionId is the foreign key in SurveyOption. While making an update query I repeatedly get an error `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_SurveyOptions_SurveyQuestions". The conflict occurred in database "MCNITemp", table "dbo.SurveyQuestions", column 'SurveyQuestionsId'.`

My ViewModel of SurveyQuestion consist of OptionList. In which each SurveyQuestion holds its own optionList of type `List<SurveyOption>` and questionList is of type `List<SurveyQuestion>`
My modify code is the following:

```
foreach (var question in questionList)
                            {
                                var options = question.OptionsList;

                                
                                foreach (var option in options)
                                {
                                    var optionData = _mcniDbContext.SurveyOptions.Where(e => e.SurveyOptionId == option.SurveyOptionId).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (optionData == null)
                                    {
                                        _mcniDbContext.SurveyOptions.Add(new SurveyOptions()
                                        {
                                            OptionValue = option.OptionValue,
                                            Description = option.Description,
                                            Sequence = option.Sequence,
                                            SurveyOptionId = option.SurveyOptionId,
                                            SurveyQuestionId = option.SurveyQuestionId
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        optionData.SurveyOptionId = option.SurveyOptionId;
                                        optionData.SurveyQuestionId = option.SurveyQuestionId;
                                        optionData.Sequence = option.Sequence;
                                        optionData.OptionValue = option.OptionValue;
                                        optionData.Description = option.Description;
                                        _mcniDbContext.Entry(optionData).State = EntityState.Modified;
                                    }
                                    _mcniDbContext.SaveChanges();
                                }

                                var questionData = _mcniDbContext.SurveyQuestions.Where(e => e.SurveyQuestionsId == question.SurveyQuestionsId).FirstOrDefault();
                                questionData.SurveyQuestionsId = question.SurveyQuestionsId;
                                questionData.SurveyMasterId = surveyMasterId;
                                questionData.QuestionText = question.QuestionText;
                                questionData.QuestionType = question.QuestionType;
                                questionData.Required = question.Required;
                                _mcniDbContext.Entry(questionData).State = EntityState.Modified;
                                _mcniDbContext.SaveChanges();

                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model you have let EF know how relationships are working. Assuming you have not used Fluent Api for desribing same, your code can be like below (code has not been test):

```
public class SurveyOptions
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SurveyOptionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SurveyQuestionId")]
    public SurveyQuestion SurveyQuestion {get;set;}
    public Guid? SurveyQuestionId { get; set; }


    public int? Sequence { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string OptionValue { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid? ImageId { get; set; }
}
```